# Deleter function for char pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I want to use a unique pointer on char pointer. I need to know in which cases a deleter function needs to be passed to unique_ptr.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> pChar(new char [size])
```

And,

```
 std::unique_ptr<char*> pChar(new char [size])
```

I guess for char[], compiler would call delete [], but what about char*?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `char[]` compiler choose `std::default_delete<char[]>`, that actually calls `delete[]`, for `char*` compiler choose `std::default_delete<char*>`, that actually calls `delete`.

However, you cannot initialize `std::unique_ptr<char*>`, as you try, since for `T`, `std::unique_ptr<T>::pointer` is simply `T*`.

You can use something like this, but I think `smart_pointer` to pointer, it's very strange

```
   char* pp = new char[1];
   auto deleter = [](char** p) { delete[] *p; };
   std::unique_ptr<char*, decltype(deleter)> p(&pp, deleter);
```

Comment: In case of std::default_delete<char*>, How would compiler know till what size it needs to delete. It will act same as free, right?

Comment: Why not just use the array specialization instead of providing a deleter?